# Retrieving user_timeline from Twitter in XML

Tags: javascript, xml, json, twitter

I'm writing a simple app in HTML and Javascript. I'm trying to retrieve my user_timeline via jQuery's .ajax() method. The problem is that I want to retrieve my timeline in XML but I'm keep failing with this simple task. Here's my code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'xml',
        url: 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=stepanheller',
        success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(req, textStatus, error) {
            console.log('error: '+textStatus);
        }

});
```

Weird thing is that when I try exactly the same thing but with JSON instead of XML then the script works.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        url: 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=stepanheller',
        success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(req, textStatus, error) {
            console.log('error: '+textStatus);
        }

});
```

Can you give me some hints what I'm doing wrong with the request? I know that I'm using old version of API but I won't deal with OAuth right now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally impossible to send a Cross-domain ajax request. It's the general rule.

**JsonP** is the classic way to work around this limitation, and there is no equivalent for Xml according to my knowledge. Depending on your browser compatibility constraints, you can use [**XHR2**](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/) to achieve this.

Otherwise, the only solution is to set up a server proxy.

```
Client --Ajax--> Your server --HttpRequest--> Twitter
```